# Strange result of using asterisk * quantifier

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I am trying to practice asterisk * quantifier on a simple string, but while i have only two letters, the result contains a third match.

```
<?php
$x = 'ab';

preg_match_all("/a*/",$x,$m);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($m);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

the result came out:

```
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
    array(3) {
     [0]=> string(1) "a"
     [1]=> string(0) ""
     [2]=> string(0) ""
    }
 }
```

As i understand it first matched a then nothing matched when b, so the result should be

```
  array(1) {
  [0]=>
    array(2) {
     [0]=> string(1) "a"
     [1]=> string(0) ""
    }
 }
```

So what is the third match?

Comment: what's the result you expect to have ?

Comment: I have mention this at the end of the question, which should only have two matches, one for the letter a and one for nothing matched, since * match zero or more.

Comment: because you have two delimeters , if you are looking for getting only a use preg_match method

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI i am not looking for getting results, i just need to understand how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From using a regex demo tool [here](https://regex101.com/r/EoxdAm/1), we can see that the first match is `a`, while the second and third matches are the zero width delimiters in between `a` and `b`, and also in between `b` and the end of the string.

Keep in mind that the behavior of `preg_match_all` is to repeatedly take the pattern `a*` and try to apply it sequentially to the entire input string.

I suspect that what you really want to use here is `a+`.  If you examine this [second demo](https://regex101.com/r/EoxdAm/2), you will see that with `a+` we only get a single match, for the single `a` letter in `ab`.  So, I vote for using `a+` here to resolve your problem.

Comment: Yes i could have used + but i need to understand how * works for further use, but back to the problem, have you tried appling `preg_replace` with the same pattern. if you tried to replace pattern with, say x you will get xxbx, would you check and tell me why this happens, because this means there a match before a

Comment: @Makiomar Your observations are consistent with my answer, since there are three matches, and hence three replacements.  Also, if you just call `preg_match`, then you get only one match (the letter `a`), because it stops at the first match.

Comment: Re-read my above comment please.  Or, better yet, read PHP's documentation which covers the behavior of these functions.

Comment: I am afraid i can't understand what you want me to, and documents doesn't offer an explanation of how regex work, rather it shows how to use regex with php or i can't find what i want,if we can transfere to a conversation i will be grateful.thank you

Comment: I have answered your original question, and in fact have gone beyond that.  If you still have other doubts, then you should open a new question, or just review a good regex tutorial.  No one is going to give you a full explanation of regex here.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression **'/a/*'** Matches zero(**empty**) or more consecutive `a` characters.

Example : if you try to match '/a*/' to an empty string it will return one match because * refer to nothing or more . [see here](https://regex101.com/r/8NrO21/1)

the **preg_match_all** continues to look until finishning processing the entire string. Once match is found, it remainds of the string to try and apply another match.